# Android autosized Table with autofilled cells?

Tags: java, android, jexcelapi

I'm currently working on an App which should display a table of data. The data shown depends on the user's choices. I want to implement this table which should be autosized and scrollable, but I can't figure out how I could do that using a loop. Maybe you guys can help me by just giving me an example of how to implement such a table, maybe even with the specified data which the user chose in the first place.

PS: The things the user can choose are e.g. date, subject and teacher, so the table has 3 columns (subject, teacher, date). I have implemented this choice already using the jexcelAPI and an xls document, the only thing I need to do now is to implement the table to show the results.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

you can actually complete your task using listview in andriod.And you will load the list of items displayed using baseadapter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yould you give me a quick example? ^^'

Comment: Do you want design or API integration?

Comment: The API integration :)

Comment: Provide sample screen shots and API